# can't remove user claim in asp Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims

i Try to update user claims in my service and at the first i should remove claims like this:

```
var userClaimCollection = this.AppUserManager.GetClaims(user.Id);
var toRemove = new List<Claim>();
foreach (var claim in userClaimCollection)
{
      if (claim.Type == group_role)
      {
           toRemove.Add(claim);                    
      }
}
foreach(var t in toRemove)
{
     Claim c = new Claim(group_role, t.Value);
     this.AppUserManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, c);
}
```

but on `RemoveClaim(user.Id,c)` i get `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` error.
what really am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

at the end i found my problem that was Identity 2.2.0 and after update to Identity 2.2.1 my problem solved.
i found my answer [here](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2509)

Comment: It might have been a good answer, but the link is dead and appears never to have been successfully archived at Archive.org. Please don't just cite links

Answer (score 2):

For deleting claims follow the steps given below,

> Step 1: fetch the claims based on the User Id

```
   var claims = await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);
```

> Step 2: Filter the needed claim from fetched claims.

```
var lastAccessedClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == claimType);
```

> Step 3:  Then, last use the removeclaim method to delete the claim for
>   the user as shown below.

```
 var resDelete = (lastAccessedClaim == null)? null: await manager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, lastAccessedClaim);
```

put the following code to get accurate result.

```
var claims = await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);
var lastAccessedClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == claimType);

var resDelete = (lastAccessedClaim == null)? null: await manager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, lastAccessedClaim);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix for this.  Simply using 2.2.1 did not work for me.  I wracked my brain on this as it seems like it should be easy to remove a claim.  But the built in manager RemoveClaim utility would fail.  I had a scenario where a claim was added twice.  And I for the life of me I could not get rid of the duplicate claim entry.

until I iterated over indentity.claims and used TryRemoveClaim().

Example here:

```
    public async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        foreach(Claim c in identity.Claims)
        {
            if (c.Type == "FullName" || c.Type == "AcctStatus")
            {
                identity.TryRemoveClaim(c);
            }
        }

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.BF_FullName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AcctStatus", user.BF_AcctStatus));
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Comment: Did that really work? Or did you just stop getting errors when trying to remove the claim? Because when I tried it, all of my old claims were still present.